# multiple join with two table with two condtions in laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel

I have notification table and quote_policy table in that 2 id will be similar. `notification.policy_id = quote_policy.policy_id` and `notification.user_id ','=','quote_policy.user_id` i have to join in the code.  got this error production.ERROR: PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1066 Not unique table/alias: 'quote_policy' in.  Please help me.

```
  $policyCreate = DB::table('notification')->select('*')
  ->join('quote_policy','notification.policy_id','=','quote_policy.policy_id' )
  ->join('quote_policy','notification.user_id ','=','quote_policy.user_id')
  ->groupBy('notification.id')
  ->get();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this Query:

```
$policyCreate = DB::table('notification')->select('*')
  ->join('quote_policy as q1','notification.policy_id','=','q1.policy_id' )
  ->join('quote_policy as q2','notification.user_id ','=','q2.user_id')
  ->groupBy('notification.id')
  ->get();
```

2nd way:

```
  $policyCreate = DB::table('notification')->select('*')
  ->join('quote_policy', function($join){
    $join->on('notification.policy_id', '=', 'quote_policy.policy_id');
    $join->on('notification.user_id','=', 'quote_policy.user_id');
  });
  ->groupBy('notification.id')
  ->get();
```